# StringTokenizer for multiple multi-charecter tokens in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

I need to split up a string according to multiple tokens which also may have multiple charecter like given bellow,

> word1:word2|word3||word4|word5|||word6|word7

I need to token the above string according to ':', '|', '||', '|||'.
Is it possible with StringTokenizer or else what is the code to tokenize it using Regular Expression split??.. Remember, i also need the token in the resulted array...

Comment: how can you differenciate '|' '||' '|||' ?

Comment: Actually i want the token '|', '||' also in the resulted array... and the word1, word2 are the column names in a DB table... And i need to genetare result as value1:value2|value3||value4|value5|||value6|value7 from the DB values..

Comment: You need the **delimiters** in the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StringUtils` Lang API.

Please find the Javadocs for the same [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

It has the following methods -

1. `Substring/Left/Right/Mid` - null-safe substring extractions
2. `SubstringBefore/SubstringAfter/SubstringBetween` - substring extraction relative to other strings

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with StringTokenizer. But this has to be multi-step process.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can split the String like this:

```
line.split ("[:|]+") 
res113: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7)
```

But what were the delimiters? Well - obviously the opposite:

```
line.split ("[^:|]+") 
res114: Array[java.lang.String] = Array("", :, |, ||, |, |||, |)
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if any API available.you can solve like below.

steps should be.

1.take String

2.define regex to be replaced //you should know them in advance

3.loop all expressions

4.replace every expression with Space.

5.now you can use String tokenizer.

```
String str="word1:word2|word3||word4|word5|||word6|word7";
    String[] tokens={"[:]","[|]{3}","[|]{2}","[|]"};
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        str=str.replaceAll(tokens[i], " ");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```